How can I backup locally my and my family members iCloud photos?
I and other members of my family have iPhones. All of us use iCloud for backups and have "Optimize iPhone Storage" and "Advanced Data Protection" enabled. Now, I would like to back up our data locally, at least our photos. The question basically boils down to: is there a  way to access original photos (live photos included) on multiple iCloud accounts simultaneously?
I don't have a Mac, but buying a Mini and having it sitting headless in a corner, pushing files to a NAS or USB drive, just to get this working would be an acceptable solution. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any reliable information, that syncing multiple iCloud accounts simultaneously would be possible in such scenario (having to log in and switch users manually is not acceptable for me).
I can also deal with scripting, containerization, virtualization etc., but I couldn't find anything, that could deal with Advanced Data Protection, so I assume an Apple device is a requirement.

You need to do some reading, and then create a plan to achieve your objective. The first thing you should read is this - it will help you understand what you're really looking at when you look at a Photos database.  Afterwards, perhaps a general search to formulate what type of backup you want to have.
